# Need a smart solution to get all the list of attributes used in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

How to get list of all attributes used in expressions, row and columns groups and filters from existing SSRS reports?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS reports are saved as .rdl files. These are actually a form of XML. All of the attributes are neatly arranged within that structure. I'm not aware of an existing tool to do what you described. You may need to develop a script to do the XML search and return the information in the format you're looking for. Consider using Python. This would also allow you to automate the search for many report files. Hope this points you in the right direction.